# WebAPI OData $format to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, odata

for my WebAPI OData application, im trying to give my client (browser) the decision what format the data output should be. as **$format** is not implemented yet in WebAPI OData, im using Raghuramn's example here: https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/5556691

```
var queryParams = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
var dollarFormat = queryParams.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "$format").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault();

if (dollarFormat != null)
{
    request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse(dollarFormat));

    // remove $format from the request.
    request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.RequestQueryNameValuePairsKey] = queryParams.Where(kvp => kvp.Key != "$format");
}
```

This works for JSON ($format=application/json;odata=fullmetadata) and JSON light (format=application/json;odata=light) but so far not for xml.

if i add **$format=application/XML** to the querystring, it still outputs to json light. how do i force XML output?

**EDIT:**

even if i *force xml* in Fiddler by sending 
*Content-type: application/xml* and 
*Accept: application/xml*
with the request, the response simply lists: 
Content-Type: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8

**EDIT 2:**

*Accept: application/atom+xml* does seem to output xml in the raw response. Unfortunately, "application/atom+xml" throws a FormatException in:

```
request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/atom+xml"));
```

Comment: Have you tried `text/xml`?

Comment: yes that also outputs json...

Comment: FYI, Raghuramn's example will fail when using the $format=application/atom+xml querystring, as the value of dollarFormat will be "application/atom xml", dues to the "+" in the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setting the request ContentType instead of the AcceptHeader did the trick:

```
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/atom+xml");
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you please tell me what versions of Web API and OData libraries you use? I'm using Web API 2.2 (5.2.2 assembly version) and OData lib v. 6.7.0.

Comment: Hi there, @stefjnl - if possible, I would like to see your client code (e.g. if you used jquery's ajax to formulate the request... what did it look like?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a search on the keywords `request.Headers.Accept.Add` and `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` that were presented by this question, I found a [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559378/Implementing-Custom-Media-Formatters-in-ASP-NET-We) that actually presented the syntax to correctly add the Accept header and solve the same issue:

```
this.Request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/atom+xml"));
```

instead of `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/atom+xml")` which throws the FormatException.