# Web API OData format as XML

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am testing a Web API project using OData and EF to return results form a SQL Server view. It took a while but I finally got it working. What I'd like to do next is use a different formatter to return the results.

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx) I should have options for atom, json, and xml using the $format parm. But this parm appears to be ignored. Digging some more I found articles similar to [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/odata-feed-using-Asp-Net-web-api/) that say you have to add commands to allow the $format parm to work but I have no reference to "Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping" which I've found in several other articles. I have seen references to testing with Fiddler and the updating to return JSON for example but I want to use $format so I can also pull different formats in SSIS.

The closest thing I find is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574061/webapi-odata-format-to-xml) but there is no solution for XML besides Fiddler and the JSON $format commands do not work for me. I assume that maybe things changed in the past 4 months.

Is there anyway to get $format to work with XML?

Comment: I'm not sure I want to mark this as a solution yet but one really horrible way to make this work was to remove JSON as an option. In the WebApConfig I am able to add the command config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter) and this takes JSON off as the default and returns XML. But, like I said, this seems like a poor solution.

Comment: [according to this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25417419/1520850) if you're using OData v4  - you cannot do it at all - but pls post back if you do figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to say this is a problem with the VB.Net version of the code. It seems to work fine if you switch to C#.

Answer (score 0):

AddQueryStringMapping is an extension method in class:
`System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterExtensions`

If that doesn't work, you can follow the example
https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/5556691 to always set the request accept header with
application/xml or application/atom+xml.

Please let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: I've added a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter but unlike the second link I referenced I still cannot see AddQueryStringMapping as an option for something like GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter. There really isn't much to the changes in that article for global.asax so while it must be something I'm doing wrong I can't see it.

Comment: Add using "using System.Net.Http.Formatting" in your code, Otherwise can you call the extension method directly "System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterExtensions.AddQueryStringMapping(formatter, "$format", "json", "application/json")". By the way, is the webapi nuget package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" added to your project?

Comment: That is what confuses me. I do have the correct "using" statement. Intellisense responds as expected right up until I look for "AddQueryStringMapping". It just isn't part of the list. That is why I started the thread. I can only think that maybe I have a corrupted install but it would be odd that it would partially function. My other thought was the method was taken away in a newer version but sounds like it should be there.

Comment: Are you using the latest version webapi 5.2? If not, you can try upgrading the webapi version.

Comment: I think the issue might be with which language you choose. I just created a simple C# WebApi project and it works as expected. But the same thing doesn't work with a VB WebApi project. Is there a reason why this would not work in a VB.Net project?