# How do I get Odata Web API to return data in the XML format

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Odata Web API service, by default this service returns data in JSON format. How can I get the data in the XML format?

Thanks

Comment: if its the MS odata tools on MVC API. you cant.
V4 dox: $metadata only in XML, queries only in JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OData V4, JSON is the default and recommended format for response payload and also the OASIS standard. So I highly recommend you to use JSON unless you have special reasons. If you have to get XML format, the thread [WebAPI OData $format to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574061/webapi-odata-format-to-xml) may be helpful.